# Удаление возвращаемых динамических объектов

Tags: c++

Доброе утро! Есть код, который выглядит примерно так:

```
vector<double>* Func(int n)
{
   vector<double> *v = new vector<double> [n];
   //здесь происходит обработка вектора
   return v;
}
```

Вопрос, как мне удалить динамический объект v, если он является возвращаемым значением? Извините за глупый вопрос, я пока новичок в кодинге.

Comment: Зачем его удалять если он вам нужен за пределами данной функции? удалять его следует после того как вы его используете

Comment: а почему все таки не написать функцию так `vector<vector<double> > Func(int n)` ?

Comment: Что-то у меня большое подозрение насчет того, что у вас [XY-проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy). Какова ваша исходная сверхзадача?

Comment: @Harry дается n некоторых записей (пусть это будет stringstream) из которых мне надо вычленить необходимые мне элементы double в n векторов. количество этих элементов мне заранее неизвестно. функция Func(int n) просто шаблон, который отображает мой вопрос. свою ошибку я уже понял :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возвращаемым значением в вашем коде является не динамический объект, а *указатель* на массив динамических объектов.

В вызывающем коде вы получите этот указатель и будете работать с ним так же, как и любым другим указателем на массив динамических объектов. Захотите удалить - удаляйте

```
vector<double> *p = Func(100);
...
delete[] p;
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по тому что в тексте вы упоминаете вектор в единственном числе, в коде имела место опечатка, и вы хотели написать:

```
vector<double> *v = new vector<double>(n); // Аллокация одного вектора, и инициализация его (длинной) n.
... 
vector<double> *v  = Func(n);
delete v;
```

Ваш исходный код:

```
vector<double> *v = new vector<double> [n]; //Аллоцирует массив из n векторов (нулевой длинны каждый).
...
vector<double> *v  = Func(n);
delete [] v;
```

Однако, возможно, вы имели ввиду просто возврат массива из функции. 
Что кажется наиболее естественным.

```
vector<double> Func(int n)
{
   vector<double> v(n); 
   //здесь происходит обработка вектора
   return v;
}
...
vector<double> v=Finc(n);
// И никакого delete! Память будет освобождена автоматически.
```

Для современных компиляторов С++, не следует бояться оверхеда, на копирование массива при возврате из функции, поскольку будет использована семантика перемещения (фактически будет скопирована пара указателей, но все "под капотом").

Comment: спасибо аз ответ! нет, мне именно нужен динамический массив размером n из векторов. Длина векторов как раз задается в коде обработки с помощью v.push_back(какой-то double).

вызов функции выглядит примерно вот так:
<code>
    vector<double> *vec = new nector<double>[n];
    vec = Func(n);
</code>

Видимо ошибка в изначальном вызове массива векторов vec?

Comment: @harald: Такой вызов функции - полная бессмыслица. Это утечка памяти.

Comment: @harald: Не инициализируйте vec начальным значением. ` vector<double> *vec = nullptr; `. Вы аллоцировали в этой строке массив, а портом "потеряли" указатель при присваивании значения из функции.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых `v` - это указатель на массив из `n` `vector<double>`. Соответственно удалять его надо через вызов `delete [](v)`. Во-вторых в записи `vector<double>* vec = new vector<double> [n]; vec = Func(n);` сначала выделяется один массив, затем значение указателя заменяется на значение указателя, возвращенного из функции, соответственно память первого массива утекает. В-третьих есть подозрение, что вам нужен был вектор из `n` элементов, а не массив из `n` векторов.

Собственно в ручном выделении памяти в этом коде нет необходимости:

```
using t_Collection = ::std::vector<::std::vector<double>>;

t_Collection Func(int n)
{
    t_Collection v{};
    v.resize(static_cast<::std::size_t>(n));
    //здесь происходит обработка вектора
    return v;
}

// использование
t_Collection v{Func(x)};
```

вариант с вектором из `n` `double`:

```
using t_Collection = ::std::vector<double>;

t_Collection Func(int n)
{
    t_Collection v{};
    v.resize(static_cast<::std::size_t>(n));
    //здесь происходит обработка вектора
    return v;
}

// использование
t_Collection v{Func(x)};
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ! нет, мне именно нужен массив из n векторов.

Comment: @harald Ну тогда вам подходит первый вариант. Там как раз будет селекция из `n` векторов и никакой мороки с ручным управлением памяти (которого следует избегать).

Comment: А теперь контрольный вопрос, @harald - чем vector отличается от массива?

Comment: @KoVadim я использовал вектор только потому, что мне неизвестно какое количество элементов будет в контейнере. если бы количество элементов было бы известно заранее, я бы использовал массив и не парился :)

а количество необходимых векторов мне известно заранее!

Comment: @harald Вы и сейчас используете массив, но с размером, неизвестным заранее, выделяя его вручную используя оператор `new []`. Вместо этого как раз имеет смыл использовать вектор (который сам выделит массив нужного размера, а затем удалит его).

Comment: @VTT скорее всего, вы правы, просто я привык так работать в C# (хотя я и в нем не особо мастак), разбрасывая операторами new направо и налево :) а когда мне потребовалось написать кое-что на C++, я столкнулся с проблемой ручной очистки памяти

Comment: в с++ в последнее время не принято разбрасываться new направо и налево. GC тут нет и он особо и не нужен. используйте вектор-векторов или `std::array<std::vector>` и будет счастье. В с++ компиляторы сейчас умные пошли и такие ручные оптимизации только могут помешать.

Comment: @harald А в (современном) С++ использовать операторы `new` и `delete` использовать вручную вообще не следует. Даже когда действительно нужен динамически выделяемые объекты следует использовать умные указатели.

Comment: спасибо за ответы и советы! просто я со школьной скамьи привык работать с массивами, умные контейнеры меня пока что немного пугают, поэтому стараюсь ими пользоваться нечасто. надеюсь, с опытом разберусь! размер массива просто поступает на мою часть кода извне, поэтому я так сказать решил, что он более-менее известен. вектора же в моем случае заполняются пушбэками, что мне было необходимо, так что пришлось их использовать

Comment: Страуструп, цитируя Степанова, говорит - нужен массив, используй вектор. Если оно как то медленно - почти всегда поможет reserve/resize.

Comment: у меня в другой части кода была еще такая структура vector<*double> *v = new vector<*double> [n]; которая в цикле for еще инициировалась и так vec[i] = new double[2]; в последствии представив, как под это все дело работать с памятью, благоразумно решил изменить структуру на два разных массива векторов из double :) еще раз спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @harald *"умные контейнеры меня пока что немного пугают"* Вот словите пару сложнообнаружимых утечек памяти или segfault'ов из-за ручного `new/delete`, и вас наоборот станут пугать именно они. :)